# Error: A default route has not been specified in the routing file in CI 3.0

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I have successfully run the test webpage in my local machine and it works! But when I uploaded it to the production server (iPage), I got this error:

> An Error Was Encountered
>   Unable to determine what should be displayed. A default route has not been specified in the routing file.

I have here the .htacess file:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|img|bg|robots\.txt)
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Outside the application folder.

and in my routes.php:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'login';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

and in my config.php:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/System';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

I have login.php inside controller folder with the ff codes:

```
 defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class login extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('login_model');
        /* enable session */
        $this->load->library('session');
    }

 public function index()
    {
        if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/index.php'))
        {
            /* Whoops, we don't have a page for that! */
               show_404();

        }

        $this->load->view('index'); 
       $this->load->view('templates/footer');   

   }
```

Am I missing or did something wrong?

Comment: Just a tip if I or someone else fall here trying to figure out this shit, just check if your ENVIRONMENT is corresponding to what you're expecting.

Answer (score 1):

CodeIgniter 3 requires that your *classes* are named in a Ucfirst manner *and* the filenames must match the class names.

Therefore, you need to rename your 'login.php' to 'Login.php', as well as change the class declaration to `class Login extends CI_Controller`.

Answer (score 0):

Your routes contain

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'login';
```

So in controller page name should be `login.php`

Inside `login.php`

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Login extends CI_Controller//check this
    {
        public function  __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
    }
```

> **Brief:** check this `class Login extends CI_Controller`

And `base_url` should be

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

Comment: Yes, inside my controller i have login.php

Comment: check file inside and base url too

Comment: `login` should be `Login`

Comment: class login extends CI_Controller {} my class name here is small. so my file name should be small caps too, right?

Comment: noo. its ok change this `class Login extends CI_Controller`

Comment: when i tried to upload a new CI 3.0 files, i got this. Please se link. http://www.bellanueskincare.com/POS/

Comment: change `login` to `Login` **inside controller**

Comment: http://www.bellanueskincare.com/System/login still an error page,
changing base_url = '' and login class name to Login

Comment: remove baseurl function in config.php

Comment: you want me to remove/comment this line ? $config['base_url'] = '';

Comment: No men. `$config['base_url'] = '';` should be empty. and `$config['index_page'] = '';` also empty

Comment: Both are now empty, i think i must stick to the newly uploaded CI files. Its much more working :)